# If I have an array of arrays, how do I separate the arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have an array that consists of other arrays, for example `[[1, 52], [30, 1], [2, 1]]`. I would like to use each individual array separately. Using a loop just breaks it down to all the numbers individually.

```
arrays = [[1, 52], [30, 1], [2, 1]]

irb(main):003:0* arrays.each do |array|
irb(main):004:1* puts array
irb(main):005:1> end
1
52
30
1
2
1
=> [[1, 52], [30, 1], [2, 1]]
```

I'd like to loop through the arrays. What function can I use for this?

I'd like `puts array` to display this instead;

```
[1, 52]
[30, 1]
[2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* looping through the arrays. The `puts` function on its own just makes that difficult to see. Try this:

```
arrays = [[1, 52], [30, 1], [2, 1]]

arrays.each do |array|
  puts array.inspect
end
```

Output:

```
[1, 52]
[30, 1]
[2, 1]
```

---

See also:

```
puts [1, 2, 3]
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
p array
```

.................................

You *are* looping through the arrays, it's just that `puts()` doesn't output an array so that it looks like an array.  When you give `puts()` an array as an argument, it outputs each element separated by newlines.

Examine the output here:

```
arrays = [[1, 52], [30, 1], [2, 1]]

arrays.each do |x|
  puts x.class
  puts x.size
  puts x[-1]
end

--output:--
Array
2
52
Array
2
1
Array
2
1
```

The output shows that `each()` assigns each inner array to the loop variable `x`.  Likewise, 
Array methods, like `size()` and `[]` work on `x`.